# splitting column of paths to two columns based on the directory and the name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Data-Frame:

```
    image_path
0      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s154-0001procstk.tif
1      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s153-0001procstk.tif
2      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s161-0001procstk.tif
3      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s160-0001procstk.tif
4      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s155-0001procstk.tif
5      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s158-0001procstk.tif
6      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s157-0001procstk.tif
7      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s159-0001procstk.tif
8      /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s156-0001procstk.tif
9   /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s158-learning_01.tif
10  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s157-learning_01.tif
11  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s159-learning_01.tif
12  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s156-learning_01.tif
13  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s161-learning_01.tif
14  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s160-learning_01.tif
```

I wish to split the data into 2 columns representing the RAW image and its corresponding segmentation maps.

There are 2 issue here:

1. there are more RAW images then segmentation maps, so I want to take only the ones that appear in both directories. The way to compare 2 files is based on `...Brightfield_s154...`, what comes after `sXXX` is not relevant.
2. The RAW images are in `07_CSWAT_plate2` dir while the segmenataion maps are in `07_CSWAT_plate2_DL`

I was able to separate create column of source dir using:

```
all_files["source"] = all_files['image_path'].map(lambda x: x.split("/")[-2])
```

Then I separated into 2 groups based on the directory:

```
all_files.groupby("source")
```

And I was stuck on the way to create a Data-Frame with 2 column which correspond to the same image file where the first column is the RAW images path and the second is the segmentation images path.

The expected output is:

```
    raw                                                                                                                                       seg
0  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s156-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s156-learning_01.tif
1  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s157-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s157-learning_01.tif
2  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s158-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s158-learning_01.tif
3  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s159-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s159-learning_01.tif
4  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s160-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s160-learning_01.tif
5  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s161-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s161-learning_01.tif
```

Would appreciate some help

Comment: Would you include an expected output dataframe?

Comment: @zabop Added the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the key from the column `image_path` on the basis of which you want to compare the file paths.
- Use boolean masking with [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to filter the corresponding `raw` and `segment` file paths.
- Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to merge these `raw` and `segment` paths based on the extracted key.

```
k = df['image_path'].str.extract(r'(Brightfield_s\d+)', expand=False)

r = df[df['image_path'].str.contains('07_CSWAT_plate2/')]
s = df[df['image_path'].str.contains('07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/')]

d = r.assign(key=k).merge(s.assign(key=k), on='key')\
                   .drop('key', 1).set_axis(['raw', 'seg'], 1)
```

Result:

```
    raw                                                                                                                                    seg
0  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s161-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s161-learning_01.tif
1  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s160-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s160-learning_01.tif
2  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s158-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s158-learning_01.tif
3  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s157-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s157-learning_01.tif
4  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s159-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s159-learning_01.tif
5  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s156-0001procstk.tif  /Users/davidsriker/Desktop/ThesisWIZ/Segmentation/SampleImages/07_CSWAT_plate2_DL/171107_Plate_2_1_w1cf-Brightfield_s156-learning_01.tif
```